# Summarizing observations within date and time boundaries in R

Tags: r, date, datetime, time, lubridate

I have a dataframe called `ActiveData` that shows the date and times (`StartDT` and `EndDT`) when individual `ID`s were active. `Active is structured like this where` StartDT`and`EndDT` are formatted in mdy_hms:

```
ID         StartDT               EndDT
1  05/05/2021 8:15:00    05/05/2021 9:15:00
2  05/05/2021 8:15:00    05/05/2021 9:15:00
3  05/05/2021 8:15:00    05/05/2021 10:15:00
…
```

I have another dataframe called `Observations` that shows observations where each `ID` observed themselves or another `ID` satisfying some variable. Here, `ID` denotes the observer and `IDobserved` denotes which `ID` was observed satisfying the variable (`ID`s can also observe themselves).

```
ID       DT                          IDobserved
1      05/05/2021 8:19:00                1
1      05/05/2021 8:20:00                1      
1      05/05/2021 8:19:00                2
2      05/05/2021 8:19:20                1
2      05/05/2021 8:19:45                3
3      05/05/2021 8:19:00                1
3      05/05/2021 8:20:00                1
3      05/05/2021 8:25:00                1
3      05/05/2021 8:45:00                3
3      05/05/2021 8:19:00                2
…
```

I want to summarize the number of times that each `ID` observed the other `ID`s (including themselves) satisfying the variable within the time constraints specified by `StartDT` and `EndDT` in the `ActiveData` dataframe, so that the final table would specify the number of observations, and the amount of time in seconds that passed between the boundaries that each `ID` was actively observing (between `StartDT` and `EndDT` in `ActiveData`). So for the data above, the final table would look like this:

```
ID   IDobserved   Observations      TimeElapsed
1         1            2             3600
1         2            1             3600
2         1            1             3600
2         3            1             3600
3         1            3             7200
3         2            1             7200
3         3            1             7200
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cool question! With your data

```
ActiveData <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~StartDT,             ~EndDT,
  1,   "05/05/2021 8:15:00", "05/05/2021 9:15:00",
  2,   "05/05/2021 8:15:00", "05/05/2021 9:15:00",
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:15:00", "05/05/2021 10:15:00"
)

Observations <- tibble::tribble(
  ~ID, ~DT,                ~IDobserved,
  1,   "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 1,
  1,   "05/05/2021 8:20:00", 1,
  1,   "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 2,
  2,   "05/05/2021 8:19:20", 1,
  2,   "05/05/2021 8:19:45", 3,
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 1,
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:20:00", 1,
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:25:00", 1,
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:45:00", 3,
  3,   "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 2
)
```

I would do

```
library(dplyr)

fmt <- "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"

ActiveData %>%
  mutate(across(-ID, ~ as.POSIXct(., format = fmt))) %>%
  purrr::pmap(\(...) {
    args <- list(...)
    Observations %>%
      mutate(DT = as.POSIXct(DT, format = fmt)) %>%
      filter(DT >= args$StartDT, DT <= args$EndDT, ID == args$ID) %>%
      count(ID, IDobserved, name = "Observations") %>%
      mutate(TimeElapsed = difftime(args$EndDT,
                                    args$StartDT,
                                    units =  "secs"))
  }) %>%
  bind_rows()
```

returning

```
# A tibble: 7 x 4
     ID IDobserved Observations TimeElapsed
  <dbl>      <dbl>        <int> <drtn>
1     1          1            2 3600 secs
2     1          2            1 3600 secs
3     2          1            1 3600 secs
4     2          3            1 3600 secs
5     3          1            3 7200 secs
6     3          2            1 7200 secs
7     3          3            1 7200 secs
```

Comment: I am trying to get this to work, but when I run your code I get the error `Error: unexpected input in:
"  mutate(across(-ID, ~ as.POSIXct(., format = fmt)))%>%
  purrr::pmap(\"` any ideas why?

Comment: You're having problems with the backslash notation that was introduced in R 4.1.0. You could update and restart R or substitute `\(...)` with `function(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method using `data.table`.

1. Convert `data.frame` to `data.table` with [`setDT`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/data.table/versions/1.14.0/topics/setDT)
2. Convert the 'DT', 'StartDT', 'EndDT' columns in both dataset to datetime class ([`mdy_hms`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lubridate/versions/1.7.4/topics/ymd_hms))
3. Create the 'Observations' column in second dataset (df2) as the number of observations per group ID, IDobserved
4. Do a join with the first data on the ID column, specify, summarise by getting the sum of difference between the DT, StartDT, EndDT columns using [`difftime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/difftime) and return the `unique` rows

```
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)
setDT(df1)[, c('StartDT', 'EndDT') := lapply(.SD, mdy_hms),
       .SDcols = 2:3]
setDT(df2)[, DT := mdy_hms(DT)]
df2[, Observations := .N, .(ID, IDobserved)]
unique(df2[df1, .(IDobserved, Observations,
      TimeElapsed = as.numeric(difftime(DT, StartDT, units = 'sec') +
        difftime(EndDT, DT, units = 'sec'))), on = .(ID), by = .EACHI])
```

-output

```
    ID IDobserved Observations TimeElapsed
1:  1          1            2        3600
2:  1          2            1        3600
3:  2          1            1        3600
4:  2          3            1        3600
5:  3          1            3        7200
6:  3          3            1        7200
7:  3          2            1        7200
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:3, StartDT = c("05/05/2021 8:15:00", 
"05/05/2021 8:15:00", 
"05/05/2021 8:15:00"), EndDT = c("05/05/2021 9:15:00", "05/05/2021 9:15:00", 
"05/05/2021 10:15:00")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))

df2 <- structure(list(ID = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
    DT = c("05/05/2021 8:19:00", "05/05/2021 8:20:00", "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 
    "05/05/2021 8:19:20", "05/05/2021 8:19:45", "05/05/2021 8:19:00", 
    "05/05/2021 8:20:00", "05/05/2021 8:25:00", "05/05/2021 8:45:00", 
    "05/05/2021 8:19:00"), IDobserved = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```